# How do I make a driven bone cause its keyframe value to change?

Tags: drivers

So I developed a method to export a face key animations via BVH.

Below is a character that has a row of bones over its head. They contain facial animation data, one bone per shape key. So all I would have to do is assign drivers for shape keys and tweak the animation as needed with a control panel.

[image]

My set up to add a control panel doesn't work. (blend file)

I want the Control panel bone(keying locked) to tweak the Data bone's keyframes while the Data bone controls the Shape key(keying locked).

Is there a way to make this set up work? Where the control panel bone both moves with the shape key values but can also drive the Data bone keyed values?

[image]

[image]